# Integration of exponential of a function of cosines

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function, special-functions

I am trying to solve an integration in the form

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{a \cos{(\theta-b)} + c \cos{(2\theta)}} d\theta$$

where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants. I know that if $c=0$, the integration reduces to $2\pi I_0(a)$. However, I want to solve it for $c\ne 0$.

Any suggestions? even in the form of a series expansion?

Thanks

Comment: Any reason in particular you're trying to solve this integral?

Comment: It pops out from some fluid mechanics equations applied to wakes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\def\I{\operatorname I}$
A [Jacobi Anger expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion) uses [Bessel I](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselI.html):

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{a \cos{(\theta-b)} + c \cos{(2\theta)}} d\theta=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}i^n(-1)^n \I_n(-a)\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i n (\theta-b)}e^{c\cos(2\theta)}d\theta$$

Substitute $2t\to t$, notice the odd terms cancel, and convert $e^{ix}\to\cos(x)$ since the sum is real:

$$\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}i^n(-1)^n \I_n(a)\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i n (\theta-b)}e^{c\cos(2\theta)}d\theta=\frac12\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}\cos(2bn)\I_{2n}(a)\int_0^{4\pi}\cos(n\theta)e^{c\cos(\theta)}d\theta$$

The integrand is symmetric, so we can integrate from $0$ to $\pi$ to get another Bessel I function. Since $\I_n(-x)=\I_n(x)$, we get a sum over the naturals. Therefore:

$$\boxed{\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{a \cos{(\theta-b)} + c \cos{(2\theta)}} d\theta=2\pi\I_0(a)\I_0(c)+4\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty\cos(2bn)\I_{2n}(a)\I_n(c)}$$

which relates to [“two variable Bessel functions”](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0608216). The result is shown here:

[image]

Comment: This is great! thanks a lot